# python сортировка колонки датафрейма по нескольким ключам

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, сортировка, dataframe

Предположим есть датафрейм такого вида (колонок может быть больше):

```
d = {'ATTRIBUTE_NAME': 
     ['Raw_Read_Error_Rate',
      'Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt',
      'Power_On_Hours',
      'Power_Cycle_Count',
      'Program_Fail_Count',
      'Erase_Fail_Count',
      'Ave_Block-Erase_Count',
      'Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct',
      'Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk',
      'SATA_Interfac_Downshift',
      'Error_Correction_Count',
      'Reported_Uncorrect',
      'Temperature_Celsius',
      'Reallocated_Event_Count',
      'Current_Pending_Sector',
      'Offline_Uncorrectable',
      'UDMA_CRC_Error_Count',
      'Percent_Lifetime_Remain',
      'Write_Error_Rate',
      'Success_RAIN_Recov_Cnt',
      'Total_Host_Sector_Write',
      'Host_Program_Page_Count',
      'FTL_Program_Page_Count']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

необходимо сделать сортировку по столбцу 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME' по такому ключу: сначала строки заканчивающиеся на 'Count', затем сортировка по длине строки, затем в лексикографическом порядке.

если нужно отсортировать простой список по подобному ключу, то это делается достаточно просто с помощью аргумента 'key':

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: (-x.endswith('Count'), len(x), x))
```

но в случае датафрейма не все так очевидно. у метода 'sort_values()' тоже есть аргумент 'key', но он принимает объект 'Series' и такой же объект возвращает.

с простой сортировкой проблем не возникает. например такие ключи по отдельности работают:

```
df.sort_values('ATTRIBUTE_NAME', key=lambda x: -x.str.endswith('Count'))
df.sort_values('ATTRIBUTE_NAME', key=lambda x: x.str.len())
```

но вот объединить эти ключи уже не получается. придумал такой неказистый способ чтобы ключ принимал и возвращал объект 'Series':

```
def multi_sort(s):
    l = sorted(s.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1].endswith('Count'), len(x[1]), x[1]))
    return pd.Series(dict(l))

df.sort_values('ATTRIBUTE_NAME', key=multi_sort)
```

но такая сортировка дает не понятный мне результат:

```
'''
             ATTRIBUTE_NAME
4        Program_Fail_Count
15    Offline_Uncorrectable
0       Raw_Read_Error_Rate
5          Erase_Fail_Count
6     Ave_Block-Erase_Count
7    Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct
14   Current_Pending_Sector
18         Write_Error_Rate
1   Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt
9   SATA_Interfac_Downshift
2            Power_On_Hours
12      Temperature_Celsius
19   Success_RAIN_Recov_Cnt
8   Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk
11       Reported_Uncorrect
20  Total_Host_Sector_Write
16     UDMA_CRC_Error_Count
13  Reallocated_Event_Count
21  Host_Program_Page_Count
3         Power_Cycle_Count
17  Percent_Lifetime_Remain
22   FTL_Program_Page_Count
10   Error_Correction_Count
```

помогите разобраться и подскажите есть ли способ сортировки по нескольким ключам как это реализовано в функции 'sorted()'?

**UPD.**

благодаря помощи @strawdog удалось понять как использовать `key` с методом `sort_values()` при сортировке столбца по нескольким ключам, спасибо ему за это:

```
df = df.sort_values(by="ATTRIBUTE_NAME",
                    key=lambda s: s.map(lambda x: (-x.endswith("Count"), len(x), x)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал сделать так:

```
def multisort(s):
    return(s.endswith("Count"), len(s))
    
df["order"] = df["ATTRIBUTE_NAME"].apply(multisort)
df = df.sort_values(by=["order", "ATTRIBUTE_NAME"],
                    ascending=[False, True]).drop(columns=["order"])
```

Вы можете в строке сверху убрать метод drop, чтобы посмотреть, какая создается колонка и как сортируется фрейм перед выводом окончательного результата.

Есть более короткий вариант c тем же результатом:

```
res = pd.Series(sorted(df["ATTRIBUTE_NAME"],
                       key=lambda x: (-x.endswith("Count"),len(x), x)))
```

получаем df (либо res, в зависимости от варианта):

```
             ATTRIBUTE_NAME
21  Host_Program_Page_Count
13  Reallocated_Event_Count
10   Error_Correction_Count
22   FTL_Program_Page_Count
6     Ave_Block-Erase_Count
16     UDMA_CRC_Error_Count
4        Program_Fail_Count
3         Power_Cycle_Count
5          Erase_Fail_Count
17  Percent_Lifetime_Remain
1   Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt
9   SATA_Interfac_Downshift
20  Total_Host_Sector_Write
8   Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk
14   Current_Pending_Sector
19   Success_RAIN_Recov_Cnt
7    Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct
15    Offline_Uncorrectable
0       Raw_Read_Error_Rate
12      Temperature_Celsius
11       Reported_Uncorrect
18         Write_Error_Rate
2            Power_On_Hours
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает отлично. Интересно, как все же работает `key` в `sort_values()`, почему у меня получился такой странный результат.

Comment: функция сортировки в методе sort_values работает не так как кажется. она должна определять порядок сортировки для серии, а не сортировать саму серию. Если вы в вашей функции multi_sort перед return выведите полученную серию на печать, то увидите, что все у вас отсортировалось как надо, однако в качестве порядка сортировки результат не имеет смысла для исходного фрейма.

Comment: спасибо, благодаря вам я теперь кажется понял как можно использовать `key` в методе 'sort_values()'